# python, grab a regex and use it in for statement

Tags: python, regex

I have a huge 'pile' of files that contain a 13 digit number and a jpg somewhere in the same file. What I'm trying to accomplish is to grab the number, find the jpg and rename it to [number].jpg. In my  mind I should find the code and use it if the file contains such a code (some files are just garbage). I tried finding the regex and succeeded. But now, if I want to use the number found in the file, I get stuck in calling the found number. What am I doing wrong? I have working code and things I tried.

This reports the last number found in all files in a directory:

```
import os
import re

dir = "products"
jpgs=[]

for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    if os.path.isfile:
        file = dir + "/" + filename
        f = open(file, 'r')
        for line in f:
            match = re.findall(r'\d{13}', line)
            jpgs.extend(match)
print jpgs[0]
```

any indention reports: `IndexError: list index out of range`

These options I tried based on some googling:

```
option:             
            if match <> "":
                getal = match[0]
                print getal
```

Result:

```
indexError: list index out of range
```

option:

```
    if match <> "":
        getal = match(0)
        print getal
```

Result:

```
typeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

option

```
    print jpgs[-1]
```

Result:

```
indexError: list index out of range
```

Option

```
    print str(match)
```

Result:

```
[]
[]
[number]
[]
[]
```

it return a whole lot of '[]''s but it does contain the numbers. My guess is that it is the result of every line.

option to remove the unwanted 'empty results'

```
print str(match).strip('[]')
```

Result: long list of empty lines, with an occasional, correct, found number. (which is hard to show because of it is a thing to highlight 'nothing' as code)

All code is well indented in the original format. What is going wrong? How can I grab the number found in a file and use it to rename the jpg?

Using python 2.7.10 on win7

example file (real deal is an xml from a store):

```
a whole lot of text
1234567890123
several lines of text
reference to /folder/folder/image.jpg
can be more text, doesn't have to
```

This works:

```
    if match:
        getal = match[0]
        print getal
```

Comment: Give us an example of the contents of a file?

Comment: What was your intent with this line: `if os.path.isfile` ?

Comment: there might be folders in the folder as well, which I want to skip. I want to look inside those folders as well, but have not searched on os.walk and how to get what I want.

Comment: example file contents added

Comment: how would `if match <> ""` catch an empty list? What you need is `if match:`

Comment: Thanks, that gives me something to build upon.

Comment: @Arie `os.path.isfile` is a function -- you never called it. Your if condition will always be true.

Comment: You can do the renaming in the loop also, not sure why you are using lists at all

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I might have misunderstood it, but I thought re.findall returns a list object? Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I tried `if os.path.isfile(filename):` but that does not work. Any hint?